# Why to keep id and frontName same in magento 2 routes config file?

Tags: magento-2.1, router

Just curious about Why to keep id and frontName same in magento 2 routes config file ?

Below is Sample frontend route xml config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="mastering" frontName="mastering">
            <module name="Mastering_SampleModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Thanks

Comment: its not mandatory to keep both value same

Answer (score 5):

The route element **id** and **frontName** attributes have the same value, but they do
not serve the same purpose.

> app/code/Mage/Example/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Mage_Example" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Route definition requires a unique **id** and **frontName** attribute values, which in our case both equal helloworld.

The **frontName** attribute value becomes the part of our URL structure. Simply put, the URL formula for hitting the Crud action goes like:

```
{magento-base-url}/index.php/{route frontName}/{controller name}/{action name}
```

For example, if our base URL were `http://domain.com/`, the full URL would be
`http://domain.com/index.php/helloworld/test/crud/`.

Note: If we have URL rewrites turned on, we could omit the index.php part.

```
namespace Mage\Example\Controller;
abstract class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

}

namespace Mage\Example\Controller\Test;
class Crud extends \Mage\Example\Controller\Test
{
    public function __construct(
        /* Code Here */
    )
    {
        /* Code Here */
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /* CRUD Code Here */
    }
}
```

Comment: vah pratik fine explanation

Comment: Happy to help. Keep helping :)

Comment: I want to achieve this url http://myproject.com/style/parameter/the-value   .is this posible?

Comment: One important thing to note here is that the naming convention for layout.xmls is `{route id}_{controller name}_{action name}.xml`. You have to keep this in mind, if your `routeId` is diferent from your `frontName`.